# Obj-c block instantiation

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures

At what time does an Obj-C block become an object? I am guessing that it is instantiated when it is assigned to a variable, passed as a parameter, returned from a function, block, or method, or executed – whichever happens first. But I have never seen documentation on this point.

And as a postscript to this question, is it the same in Swift?

Comment: A block becomes object when you write the trailing `}`.

Answer (score 2):

A block doesn't "become" an object. It *is* an object. A block literal evaluates to a pointer to the block object.

Closures in Swift are not objects.

Comment: Let me refine my question, it's about when does instantiation occur. Yes, a block literal evaluates to a pointer to the block object. So when is the literal evaluated?

Comment: Suppose I have a factory method that returns a block written as a literal in the method body. Does the method return the same (==) object every time it executes?

Comment: @DavidCasseres: The specification gives no guarantees about whether it is the same object or not. If the block captures local variables from the surrounding scope (i.e. it's a closure), then it may not be possible to be the same object because the value of the variables it captures can have different values during different runs of the method. If the block does not capture local variables (non-closure), then it can be made to return the same object, and the current implementation allocates non-closure blocks statically -- there is one object that lives for the duration of the program

Comment: @DavidCasseres: So in the current implementation, closure block objects are created when the block literal is evaluated (i.e. when the code gets to the block literal expression). They are first allocated on the stack (`NSStackBlock`), and when copied it returns a block object that is allocated on the heap (`NSMallocBlock`). For non-closure blocks, one object is allocated in static storage at the beginning of the program, like static objects in C++. All evaluations of the block literal return a pointer to this object.